# Stuck ContextMenuStrip In Bottom Of Form

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

i use a **scrollable** form in visual studio 2022,also i use contextmenustrip.problem is when the form is long,contextmenustrip doesn't in right place in **design time** so i can't use it,it's mean i can't create toolStripMenuItem automatically and contextmenustrip stuck at bottom of form.

in below pictures you can see problem better:

[image: contextmenustrip problem image]

[image: tree of controls]

what should i do?

Comment: Why do you keep removing the image?

Comment: i can't see the image,can you?

Comment: Yes.  Maybe just refresh the page?  Maybe you can't see images from imgur.com, where it's linked from?

Comment: if you can see the image so there is no problem

Comment: Maybe OP means the contextstrip is in the tray at the bottom  of the  forms designer?

Comment: @Saber open the Document Outline window (view menu,, other windows I think) and show us the tree of controls - I want to see where the CMS is in the hierarchy    .

Comment: @CaiusJard i added what you said

Comment: @JohnG i docked two tablelayoutpanel to top of the form and form is long, also i meant that contextmenustrip is unreachable at design time not runtime

Comment: Temporary set `AutoScroll = false` when you want to edit the CMS.

Comment: @dr.null your right but i need a long form so i need autoscroll be available

Comment: `true` it back when you finish editing the CMS?

Comment: @dr.null when i set autoscroll of form to false,contextmenustrip stay at bottom of form(According to the image I posted) and getting unreachable

Comment: Yes you're right. In this case, use the CMS items editor to create the menu. Select the CMS, hit F4 to switch to the Properties window, the `Items` property (default) is selected, click the `...` button to open the editor, add/remove/move items and set their properties in there....